# Ceiling Fan and separate ceiling light fixtures

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting, ceiling-fan

I just replaced my ceiling fan in the kitchen (has no lights). I also have a separate light fixture.  Before replacing the ceiling fan, I would turn on one switch to turn the fan on or off, and the second switch to turn the lights on or off.  After replacing the ceiling fan (has no lights) when I turn on the light switch (dimmer) the lights dim and all is good.  However when I turn on the fan switch the lights automatically come on and I cannot dim them. My previous fan did not have lights.

I wired everything it seems as it was before, however I now have this problem with the fan switch?  Any suggestions or a proposed wiring diagram.

Comment: Did the previous fan have a light?

Comment: There are too many variations in wiring for this to just draw them all out. If you can post a (partial) diagram, showing which wires are in each location and how it's currently wired up, that would be a good start.

Comment: I edited the relevant parts of your answer into the question. Please see http://meta.diy.stackexchange.com/q/523/22 for instructions on adding pictures to a post.

Answer (score 1):

You would appear to have the lights connected to BOTH the dimmer and the fan switch. Presumably this means that things are not really wired the way they were before. You'll need to figure out where this happened and correct it; it's difficult to speculate from afar, but when you get beyond what you can sort out yourself, call in a pro.